# UISearchBar overlaps with UINavigationBar?

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints, uisearchbar

I added a UISearchBar to the below viewController programmatically as illustrated in the below code:

```
import UIKit

class BlueBookUniversalBeamsVC: UIViewController, UINavigationBarDelegate {

    lazy var navigationBar = CustomUINavigationBar(rightNavBarTitle: "Sort Data", rightNavBarTitleHexColourCodeNormalState: "#333301", rightNavBarTitleHexColourCodeHighlightedState: "#FFFF05", rightNavBarButtonTarget: self, rightNavBarSelector: #selector(navigationBarRightButtonPressed(sender:)), isNavBarTranslucent: false, navBarBackgroundColourHexCode: "#CCCC04", navBarBackgroundColourAlphaValue: 1.0, navBarStyle: .black, preferLargeTitles: false, navBarDelegate: self, navBarItemsHexColourCode: "#E0E048", normalStateNavBarLeftButtonImage: "normalStateBackButton", highlightedStateNavBarLeftButtonImage: "highlightedStateBackButton", navBarLeftButtonTarget: self, navBarLeftButtonSelector: #selector(navigationBarLeftButtonPressed(sender:)), labelTitleText: "Universal Beams (UB)", titleLabelFontHexColourCode: "#FFFF52", labelTitleFontSize: 16, labelTitleFontType: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Light")

    var searchBar = UISearchBar()

    var isSearching = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupSearchBar()

        UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]

        view.addSubview(navigationBar)

        view.addSubview(searchBar)

    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            navigationBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),

            navigationBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),

            navigationBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor)

            ])

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

        setupConstraints()

    }

    @objc func navigationBarLeftButtonPressed(sender : UIButton) {

    }

    @objc func navigationBarRightButtonPressed(sender : UIButton) {

    }

    func position(for bar: UIBarPositioning) -> UIBarPosition {

        return UIBarPosition.topAttached

    }

    func setupSearchBar() {

        searchBar.delegate = self

        searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    }

    func setupConstraints() {

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            searchBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),

            searchBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: navigationBar.frame.size.height),

            searchBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),

            ])

    }

}

extension BlueBookUniversalBeamsVC: UISearchBarDelegate {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if searchText.isEmpty == false {

            filteredArrayOutOfUniversalBeamsArrayDataExtractedFromTheCsvFileUsingTheParserAsPerSearchedCharacters = universalBeamsArrayDataExtractedFromTheCsvFileUsingTheParser.filter({ $0.fullSectionDesignation.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased() })

            isSearching = true

        } else {

            isSearching = false

        }

    }

}
```

However, when I run and test the App as illustrated in the attached image, it can be seen that the UISearchBar overlaps with the UINavigationBar. I can still tap the UINavigationBar left and right buttons, however, for some reason the UISearchBar overlaps the UINavigationBar over a specific distance. Any idea why I am getting this kind of behaviour? As ideally I would like my UISearchBar to appear directly underneath the UINavigationBar and its height to be equivalent to the height of the textField inside of it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR6Al.png)

Comment: Screenshot looks the navigation bar shows 'Large Title' I think. How about change values of `navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode` to `.never` and `navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles` to `false`?

Comment: Thanks @CenoX for getting back to me but I already have navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles toast to false.

Comment: Hmm.. I see. then, how about ensure your view hierarchy is same what you thinking and add here for more information?

you can check from bottom debugger bar on Xcode. https://imgur.com/a/N2ozVuI

Comment: Well as far as I can tell from the Debug View Heirarchy, the overlap is due to the huge size of the UISearchBarBackground. Any idea how can I change its height?

Comment: `searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: <YOUR VALUE>).isActive = true`

Answer (score -1):

It turned out that I just needed to change the order of the added subViews as illustrated below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupSearchBar()

        UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]

        view.addSubview(searchBar)

        view.addSubview(navigationBar)

    }
```